# The logic of nested loops in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming and I'm following the CS50 course. I'm trying to fully understand the logic behind nested loops in C. I think I've got it, but I'd like to be sure before I move on to the next set of problems. Here's the code (provided by the course). It creates a cube made of hashes. My explanations are below the code.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n, j++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The first loop starts: It creates a new variable called i and sets it to 0. The command checks the new variable: If it is lesser than n (true), run it, starting the inside loop.

The inside loop also creates a new variable, j, sets it to 0, checks it and, if it is true (j < n), runs the code below and print a hash. Afterwards, the inside loop is incremented and this process occurs again until the inside loop condition is not met anymore. This will create a ROW of hashes if n is greater than 2.

The outer loop creates a new line, increments and the process starts all over again. It will run until the condition is false (i > n).

The next times the inside loop is accessed, the variable j is set to 0 again, that's why it is possible to print various rows in this program.

Is that correct? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That sounds about right, your [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) seems to have worked. I also recommend that you learn how to use an actual debugger, as then you can use it to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values and see them change in "real time".

Comment: You need to remove the semicolons after the `for` loops. As is, exactly one `#` will be printed.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! This ruber duck debugging concept is very helpful! I didn't know about it. And I'm already trying to figure it out how debuggers work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is spot on.

With a minor mistake:

> It will run until the condition is false (i > n).

The condition is false when `i >= n`.

And what I assume it's a typo:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n, j++);
//                         ^
//                         |
```

remove the `;`

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it was a typo. I'm not very used to the programming synthax yet...